# Find the acute angle of the intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Show that both lines $r=(3,9)+t(2,5)$ and $r= (-5,6)+t(3,-1)$ contain the point $(1,4)$. Find the acute angle of intersection.

I have found the two lines, and sketched them but how do I find the acute angle?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the angle between the vectors that define the directions of the lines; namely, between $(2,5)$ and $(3,-1)$. And if that angle is obtuse, use its supplement.

Do you know how to find the angle between two vectors? There are several ways.

1) The Law of Cosines, treating those two points and the origin as a triangle.

2) The two different definitions of the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

3) The two different definitions of the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). This would involve treating the vectors as three-dimensional ones.

4) Finding the direction angle of each vector with respect to the positive $x$-axis by using the arctangent or [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function, and subtracting the two direction angles.

There are still other methods.

Comment: Would I use cosine law? And just out of curiosity what are the other methods?

Comment: Thanks a ton! This helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

here is a more elementary way to find the angle if you don't know the dot product but know the cosine rule.  you have the point $C = (1, 4)$ and points $A = (3,9), B= (-5, 6)$ on each of the lines.  $$a^2 = BC^2 = 2^2 + 6^2, b^2 = AC^2 = 5^2 + 2^2, c^2 = AB^2 = 3^2 + 8^2.$$  you want to find $C$ use $$\cos C = \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}. $$